# Setting closure's delegate in method results in SO

Tags: groovy, closures, dsl

I'm using the following [code with builder](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_4_0&codez=eNp9UctugzAQvPsr9gZIqaOmZyr1QatKlSo1XHqqaFgsKmMjs1ChKP9eP4BwSS7GzOzO7ozrptWGQBith5GPRSP5lz0e-1qWaBh7krrrDYJA-vj5xQNBCkfYk6mVAJ2PLcLNPQMwSL1RcLRXAHKwJ_1vpU1TEES1ortdZKETOzFWYgW1qmRBGMM85hC-GyhRorAUJF5zwvkCp0vFijXYaTmg3c7iYrRFky5_zt6z14c8-355-9zn55Y4mVdx1m2Dwj9YBWB5R7gVuuA5GgrZo3OhfR63wfJswFtPV3E51yjQREsyF0wE0g50-czqu6C-3V7Wl1qJaKq6Kh9oPwDm5M9C8aQEyWbd5p-qtc5JKp8RJx1eP07-AYVbt8o):

```
Closure getObject = { String oType ->
  return {
    type oType
    format 'int32'
  }
}

def yaml = new YamlBuilder()
yaml{
  string 'value'
  object1{
    Closure type = getObject 'integer'
    type.delegate = delegate
    type()
  }
  object2{
    Closure type = getObject 'long'
    type.delegate = delegate
    type()
  }
}

println yaml.toString()
```

The code works as expected and produces correct yaml.

Now I want to remove repeating lines of code and introduced the `inflate()` method:

```
def inflate( Closure closure, delegate ) {
  closure.delegate = delegate
  closure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
  closure()
}
```

so that my DSL gets more compact:

```
yaml{
  string 'value'
  object1{
    inflate getObject( 'integer' ), delegate
  }
  object2{
    inflate getObject( 'long' ), delegate
  }
}
```

This led to the SOE:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Script1$_run_closure1$_closure3.doCall(Script1.groovy:5)
    at Script1$_run_closure1$_closure3.doCall(Script1.groovy)
```

What am I missing?

The script can be played with [on appSpot](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_4_0&codez=eNp9UctugzAQvPsr9gZIqaOmZyr1QatKlSo1XHqqaFgsKmMjs1ChKP9eP4BwSS7GzOzO7ozrptWGQBith5GPRSP5lz0e-1qWaBh7krrrDYJA-vj5xQNBCkfYk6mVAJ2PLcLNPQMwSL1RcLRXAHKwJ_1vpU1TEES1ortdZKETOzFWYgW1qmRBGMM85hC-GyhRorAUJF5zwvkCp0vFijXYaTmg3c7iYrRFky5_zt6z14c8-355-9zn55Y4mVdx1m2Dwj9YBWB5R7gVuuA5GgrZo3OhfR63wfJswFtPV3E51yjQREsyF0wE0g50-czqu6C-3V7Wl1qJaKq6Kh9oPwDm5M9C8aQEyWbd5p-qtc5JKp8RJx1eP07-AYVbt8o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, that instead of a method a Closure should be used.

In this case the closure nesting and reuse is not a problem any more:

```
import groovy.yaml.YamlBuilder

Closure inflate = { Closure closure, del ->
  closure.delegate = del
  closure()
}

Closure getObject = { String oType ->
  return {
    type oType
    format 'int32'
  }
}

Closure getNestedObject = {
  return {
    type 'object'
    nested{
      inflate getObject( 'nested' ), delegate     
    }
  }
}

def yaml = new YamlBuilder()

yaml{
  string 'value'
  object1{
    inflate getObject( 'integer' ), delegate
  }
  object2{
    inflate getNestedObject(), delegate    
  }
}

println yaml.toString()
```

prints

```
---
object1:
  type: "integer"
  format: "int32"
object2:
  type: "object"
  nested:
    type: "nested"
    format: "int32"
```

The runnable code [is here](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_4_0&codez=eNp1UbFugzAQneuvuM0gtUhJ5nZo93ZIl44kHJYrYyNzJEKIf4_tE4FECYOx3_m9d--sm9Z5AuWdOw3FUDam-AvLZ69NhV6IL-O63iNoW5uSEN5hhBk78v8VKjTw9iFgRooAoOLrYbsUslxMi6ZC-jn845GS6p68tgrc79Aiq3mk3lsYwxaAIpyK6Vg735QEUlvabWWApjvlb-wIq0X_oZ50qS4TYhODq3ANfG0yA8k3JOQpMieMX6JMcxMV1hAHGVwtnmE1zhBfxEr06DiuPJWmx9gAt7Jh_0fuISoq9Df2gn2Zu33ONc6q58TdKF5WrPXosrusc8g2dE_GpqAFOX68LL8A_6G6sg)

Answer (score 3):

Not 100% sure what's going on, but this seems to work

```
Closure getObject = { String oType, del ->
  { ->
    type oType
    format 'int32'
  }.tap { 
      it.delegate = del
      it.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
  }
}

def yaml = new YamlBuilder()
yaml{
  string 'value'
  object1{
    getObject('integer', delegate)()
  }
  object2{
    getObject('long', delegate)()
  }
}
```

Comment: I do need to apply the delegate in a "proxy"-method as I have tens of closures and many of them are nested